# Problems with login: unreadable flashing error

Tags: 11.04, startup, logging

I'm having problems with loggin in on Ubuntu 11.04. I did an install on my laptop after I had Windows 7 installed (dual boot with `grub`). All went well, but when I am about to login on Ubuntu it gives a short flashing error. Which is unreadable because it flashes.

I'm sure it isn't a wrong password because i can login with Ctrl+alt+f1.

Does anyone have the same problem or knows a fix for it?

[edit]

Opened file: `more /home/teun/.xsesssion-errors`

Could not parse arguments: Kan display niet opnemen.

```
(Polkit-gnome-authentication-agent:1371): GTK warning cannot open display:0
(Polkit-gnome-authentication-agent:1370): GTK warning cannot open display:0
(nm-applet:1379): GTK warning cannot open display:0
```

Also:

```
 gnome-session : fatal io error 11 on x server :0
 gnome-settings-daemon: Fatal io error 104 on  x server :0
 process:1368: Glib-Gobject-Critical ** G_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECY (object)' Failed.
```

Comment: Errors regarding logging into the desktop are logged in the file `.xsession-errors` in your home directory. Have a look in there after you login with control-alt-f1 (with `more /home/{your_loginname}/.xsession-errors`)

Comment: Add it to your question ;) and did you try to start gnome as root perhaps?

Comment: @Teun `sudo startx&&sudo gnome-session`

Comment: Join us here Teun: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room

Comment: you can now, so join the chat! :)

Comment: how do i do this: 
export DISPLAY=:0.0

into your /root/.bashrc

Comment: @Teun Schriks `sudo nano /root/.bashrc`, append `export DISPLAY:0.0` to it, Ctrl + X, Y.

Comment: It is because i have Nvidia driver.
Login at ubuntu classic.
Then update the drivers.

This also may help after updating:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Comment: If this was an NVidia driver problem - and that resolved this, could you report that comment as an answer and mark it so please?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/65852/cannot-login-to-my-user-account/67959

Answer (score 1):

have you installed any gtk dev packages recently? this looks like a deprecated version error, or it's a problem with emerald. Try changing your theme. If that doesn't work, try reinstalling glib, something like this: `sudo aptitude install glib` should list the availible packages for install, or `wget http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/glib/2.30/glib-2.30.1.tar.bz2` then build from source or use aptitude. If it still doesn't work after that than post the full `/.xsession-errors` file