# Can't login after installing 11.10

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot login to my user account](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65852/cannot-login-to-my-user-account)

This computer has had Ubuntu on it for quite some time, and after several upgrades, the OS started getting a little creaky. I decided to reinstall, but I wanted to keep my files, which was easy because `/home` was in a different partition.

During the installation, I chose to reformat my `/` partition, and use (but not format) my `/home` partition. I also ended up changing my password to something more secure. The install seemed to go OK, so I rebooted into the system.

I was presented with the new login screen, which I filled out and tried to log in. The screen flashed to black, sometimes showing a virtual terminal, and then put me back to the login screen. This happens regardless of whether I choose the "Ubuntu" or "Ubuntu 2D" session.

I switched to a virtual terminal and was able to login, but found my home directory empty, save two files telling me how to decrypt my drives. I ran the decryption command, and my files showed up. I assume because my password changed, this no longer happens automatically.

I'm running an ATI Radeon HD 5830 card on a 64-bit processor.

**TL;DR**:

- I can no longer login to my computer.
- My home directory no longer decrypts automatically.

Comment: Can you login on the console? If so, try running a separate X using `startx gnome-session-fallback -- :1` first. How specifically is your home directory encrypted? With that userspace encfs thing? -- The login problem might just be a stale `.Xauthority`. Delete them. Worked for me. (Just now.)

Comment: That gives me a black screen. The drive is encrypted using eCryptFS, the default thing that comes with Ubuntu.

Comment: Deleting the `~/.Xauthority` worked. Mind turning that into an answer and explaining what it's for?