# Install 12.04 alongside 11.04, having a share /home, but I cannot login into 12.04

Tags: login

I have 11.04 installed in my computer, and I decided to install 12.04 from CD in a new partition, but having only one `/home` partition shared by both systems.

Installation went ok, but when I enter my password the screen turns black and returns to the login screen half a second later.

I can log in as guest. I can also login at the cmd prompt (going to tty with `Alt`+`Ctrl`+`F1`) with my normal user credentials. When logged in as guest I can also install programs using my normal account password.

LinuxIsMyFriend had the same issue, and he answered the issue himself saying

*When I created my new user (with the same name as the old one) I got the correct home directory but wrong`UID` and `GID`. When I changed it to the correct values everything worked again!*

I'd like to do what LinuxIsMyFriend did, but I do not how. My question is, what should I do to set the proper `UID` and `GID` in the 12.04 install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran out that bug this morning, and it seems that I had some file under my /home/ dir wich were associated to root ownership (in this case, .Xauthority and other ones). I changed owner of .Xauthority to my username and it works now.

---

While I wrote this I saw other similar posts on this website, it's not a 12.04 problem, but the bad guy is always this .Xauthority. Deleting it or changing owner seems working

@see [Can't login after installing 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66482/cant-login-after-installing-11-10)

Answer (score 0):

Boot up a rescue cd, which could be Ubuntu or not, then mount both roots, edit `/etc/passed` of the new version so that the `UID` of the user equals that of the old version. Do the same with `/etc/group`. Now you boot into 12.04 you should have no `/home` directory issue, assuming your passwd is correct. If you are not sure, you can copy the old passwd from `/etc/shadow` and put in the new version file, while you fixed `UID` and `GID`.

Comment: I checked both passwd and group file, and UID and GID are the same there. I also did copy the shadow files from the 11.04 system to the 12.04 one. Still the same situation.