# Can't login into Ubuntu

Tags: 11.10, xorg, login, login-screen

I started having this issue after having removed Kubuntu from my computer. At first login screen wouldn't even show, instead the screen stopped at `Checking Battery state` stage. At this point I still could use `startx` after <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. Then I reinstalled and reconfigured dmg and `ubuntu-desktop` a number of times, so I got my login screen back. Now, everytime I get to the login screen, my user name shows up but password is not requested, just an 'Access' button shows, and if I click the button the screen just goes black for a second and then I'm back to the login screen. I can get into Ubuntu only via Guest account. In addition, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and `startx` doesn't work anymore, giving me an output that ends like this:

```
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

Since I believe this is somehow related to an X issue, I took a log of `Xorg.0.log`, [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/714795/) is the link.
Hope someone has a solution.

Answer (score 1):

[linux.die.net/man/1/startx](http://linux.die.net/man/1/startx)

What I'm finding is that your log file has a lot of files missing. This probably leads to the errors, either way it seems like startx is trying to load up a GUI that doesn't exist.

Now what you'd need to do is get into the command line and reinstall the packages for either KDE or GNOME. It's likely that the packages are corrupted in some way.

Comment: In the end, I worked it out with [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65852/cannot-login-to-my-user-account/67723#67723).

Comment: Anyway, do you think I'm gonna have trouble with all those missing packages?