# Login redirects back to login screen

Tags: 11.10, login

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 which was working fine till today.

If I try to login using one of my user accounts it directs me back to the login screen, which is followed by a black screen.

I am sure the password I enter is correct because if the password is wrong it prompts "Invalid Password".

On the other hand I am able to login using a root or guest account.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a problem with the `.Xauthority` file for that account - see [Cannot login to my user account](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65852/cannot-login-to-my-user-account)