# Ubuntu is booting into terminal instead of GUI Interface

Tags: 12.04, command-line, boot, upgrade, interface

I recently upgraded my computer to Ubuntu 12.04 from 10.04 and it started messing up, as in, freezing up on certain programs and then randomly logging out and going to the log-in screen.  I've done all of the upgrades and it still wasn't working properly.

Now when I turn the computer on, instead of booting to the GUI Interface, it boots straight to the terminal.  Is there any command I can type to boot it properly?  And if so, what do I do to keep it booting properly?

I did some research and found that some people used the "startx" command, but it didn't work for me.  This is what it said:

"X: user not authorized to run the X server, aborting.
X10:  fatal 10 error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 7 requests (7 known processed) with 0 events remaining."

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does `sudo startx` give you?

Comment: @Melon

sudo startx gives me:

"Fatal server error:
Server is already active for display 0
        If this server is no longer running, remove    /tmp/.X0-lock and start again.

Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support at http://wiki.x.org for help.

ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
"X: user not authorized to run the X server, aborting.
XIO: fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0" after 7 requests (7 known processed) with 0 events remaining."

Comment: Can you show us the contents of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`

Comment: @Melon I tried, but it says "bash: /var/log/Xorg.0.log: permission denied"

I was finally able to log in to the GUI Interface. I'm not exactly sure how I did it, I just fiddled around. One thing is weird, though. I'm only able to log in as guest, not as my actual name. I do have a password, but it keeps saying that it's incorrect. So, now I'm logged in as a guest and I am able to use the terminal. I just don't know where to go from here...

Comment: Well, you can show the contents of the file with `sudo`. Also, can you switch to root with `sudo su` ?

Comment: @Melon I probably sound really dumb asking this, but how do I do that? I'm probably just not understanding the question. EDIT: I'm responding to you on a separate computer than the one that has the actual problem, in case I'm suppose to attach something from the defective computer.

Comment: If you type `sudo su` you will be asked for root password. You mentioned earlier, that you can type commands (as a guest). So try that and we can think of something from there

Comment: @Melon I typed it and this is what I got: "sudo: unable to change to sudoers gid: Operation not permitted, sudo: setresuid() [0, 0, 0] -> [121, -1, -1]: Operation not permitted"

EDIT: I also followed these directions to try and change the password to see if I could log in my regular account, but I still wasn't able to log in. http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Comment: Hm. Do you have an external IP and an `easy` password?

Comment: Well, the only thing that I could imagine right now is that someone hacked your computer. If your password is `easy` to crack and have an external IP this could be done really fast. My friend once set up an external IP and while browsing through the logs, he saw that many times somebody tried to login as root. Another option is that you installed some `malware`. I cannot find any other reason why you suddenly cannot login as a normal user. Maybe some experienced users would help here?

Aubrey: Please edit out you IP just in case. I don't want to know your IP, only if it is external.

Comment: @Melon Oh dear. Well, thank you for helping me. Do you know who I can contact about it? And do you know of any way of how to decipher if it's a malware problem or a security problem?

Comment: @Melon, Also, I wasn't able to edit out my IP so I just deleted the comment.

Comment: @Melon I found a fix! http://askubuntu.com/a/67723 Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Hehe, don't know how I could have helped, but glad you found the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay everybody, it's fixed! Here's what fixed it: https://askubuntu.com/a/67723

Thanks to everyone who helped!

Answer (score 0):

Once you are connected, write `sudo init 5` in the terminal prompt.

Comment: I tried the "sudo init 5" in the terminal prompt, but because I'm only able to log in as guest, I'm denied permission to use any sudo commands. This is what it said when I entered it: "sudo: unable to change to sudoers gid: Operation not permitted
sudo: setresuid() [0, 0, 0] -> [125, -1, -1]: Operation not permitted"

Comment: I really need to figure out a way to log back in to my regular account. It tells me my password is incorrect, but I know it's not. I even changed it through the root menu, but it still didn't work. Once I can figure out how to log into my regular account, then I should be able to use the sudo command. The problem is figuring out how to get in...

Comment: I found a fix! http://askubuntu.com/a/67723 Thanks for trying to help me.