# sudo su command not working

Tags: 12.04, sudo, command-line, permissions, malware

Previous happenings here: [Ubuntu is booting into terminal instead of GUI Interface](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231850/ubuntu-is-booting-into-terminal-instead-of-gui-interface)

For some reason when I boot my computer up, instead of automatically entering into my normal interface, I have to chose between my account and the guest account. When I try to log into my account, it tells me that my password is incorrect. It is NOT incorrect. I even changed it through the root menu and it still didn't work. So, I'm having to log in as a guest.

I have tried the command "sudo su" several times. And each time I do, it comes up with this: "sudo: unable to change to sudoers gid: Operation not permitted
sudo: setresuid() [0, 0, 0] -> [124, -1, -1]: Operation not permitted"

I'm assuming it's because I'm in guest, but every time I try to type in a command, it tells me "permission denied" or something of that sort. I really need to log in to my regular account. It's not a password issue. In my recent post that I linked, I was told that it was probably either a malware issue (which I'm unsure of how to get rid of) or a security issue, as in, someone hacked into my computer. I'm not sure which it is. But I desperately need help. I have done nothing but research every response that I'm getting from the command-line, but everything that I've found hasn't helped because, like I said, every command I try to type just denies me permission.

If this is a malware issue, how do I fix it? If it is a security issue, how do I fix it? I'm not new to Ubuntu, but I've never had a problem like this before until I upgraded to 12.04. Please, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, Im afraid I am not sure what to do with your Normal account, but yes you are right, Guest account will not have the permission to SU. Also it is **recommended** to prefix the commands with `sudo` instead of using `su`.

Comment: @KarthikT Thanks for letting me know. I just wish I knew of a way to log in, or why it's even messing up.

Comment: @KarthikT I found a fix! http://askubuntu.com/a/67723

Comment: great to hear that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some help from my brother and doing some more research, I found a fix!

https://askubuntu.com/a/67723