# "/etc/X11/X not executable" error when startx

Tags: xorg, lightdm, desktop-environments, x11

**What happened**

I wanted to install KDE and Gnome along with Unity. I don't know when I installed gnome-shell on my Ubuntu 12.10, but I installed KDE minimal desktop just now using

```
sudo apt-get install kde-plasma-desktop
```

and selected lightdm as my default DM. Then I entered this to install gnome

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

and it said I already have it installed.

So, then I restarted in normal mode and Ubuntu didn't start.

**Problem**

I went to recovery mode and from root shell I used

```
startx
```

it throws these bunch of errors:

```
/etc/X11/X is not executable
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

and when I tried

```
chmod +x /etc/X11/X
```

it says

```
chmod: cannot operate on dangling symlink `/etc/X11/X'
```

I can't use apt-get to reinstall packages, because our ISP uses portal login - and I don't know how to login from terminal (so can't connect to network). May be I can use live disk, but I don't know how to configure packages on my HD from livedisk.

I am on Windows 8 now. Any help regarding how can I get my desktop back is appreciated!

Comment: Does /usr/bin/Xorg exist and is it executable? The error message says that the symlink from /etc/X11/X to /usr/bin/Xorg is broken.

Comment: @EdManet: No. There is no folder or file with name xorg or Xorg in /usr/bin. I don't understand what went wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am writing an answer for my question, but actually I haven't figured out exactly what happened that gave rise to those errors.

I am assuming that the whole xorg itself broke and I got my desktop back by using a live disk and chrooting (yeah - had to do that as its hard to connect to internet from terminal and its lot more easier to connect to internet from live disk and copy resolv.conf from here to there).

So, after creating a live disk and in Try Ubuntu mode, I chrooted into old partitions (I followed the guide [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Change_Root)) and did

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg
apt-get install --reinstall gdm gnome-desktop-environment xorg
```

Then I changed my default display manager to gdm at /etc/X11/default-display-manager by changing this line (I think this step is not needed if after a restart your desktop is working fine, but I basically did a couple more things than said above and [broke](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65852/cannot-login-to-my-user-account) lightdm too, so I had to change to gdm!)

```
/usr/sbin/lightdm
```

to

```
/usr/sbin/gdm
```

and restarted. Well, unity is working and I got my desktop back working.

Comment: required a change on apt-get cli => `apt-get install xserver-xorg --reinstall`

Comment: It's `--reinstall` ; great answers

Answer (score 10):

you have to try this

```
 sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg
```

Comment: It says:

    ln: failed to create symbolic link `/etc/X11/X': File exists

Comment: Try deleting the broken symlink first.  rm /etc/X11/X

Comment: deleted it and tried to startx. It says: X: cannot stat /etc/X11/X (No such file or directory), aborting.

Comment: @EdManet: I got it back working, somehow... I posted it as an answer. However, I don't feel that my answer is a perfect answer for this question. Seems like I broke xorg while installing those packages, but couldn't figure out what happened exactly but somehow got ubuntu working again. What do you guys think might have happened? and again, thanks for your help!

Comment: I got this after updating HWE, then cleaning package config from ubuntu-tweak. Thus --purge removes the link because xserver-xorg was replaced with xserver-xorg-lts-<release>. I've seen this both with precise with trusty HWE and trusty with utopic HWE.  doing `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg-lts-utopic` fixed it