# Ubuntu boots on terminal only, how do I recover the GUI desktop?

Tags: 12.04, unity, package-management, desktop-environments

Where is my Ubuntu desktop? Its booting and going always default to terminal screen, if i press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> still in terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> still in terminal.

[image]

No GUI, how do I recover it?

***EDIT:***

```
sun@e700gent:/etc/X11$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
[sudo] password for sun: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libcdio-paranoia1 packagekit-backend-aptcc gdebi-core libxrandr-ltsq2 linux-headers-3.5.0-23-generic linux-headers-3.5.0-23 libcdio-cdda1 libllvm3.1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 209 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/4,016 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 230006 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace ubuntu-desktop 1.267.1 (using .../ubuntu-desktop_1.267.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement ubuntu-desktop ...
Setting up ubuntu-desktop (1.267.1) ...

sun@e700gent:~$ unity --reset
WARNING: no DISPLAY variable set, setting it to :0

(process:2541): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
//bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.

WARNING: environment is incorrect: No D-BUS daemon running

Did you just try to reset in a tty?
unity-panel-service: no process found
compiz (core) - Fatal: Couldn't open display :0




sun@e700gent:~$ sudo startx
[sudo] password for sun: 


X.Org X Server 1.11.3
Release Date: 2011-12-16
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.42-37-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux e700gent 3.5.0-36-generic #57~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 20 18:21:09 UTC 2013 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-36-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=68af0547-17ed-4a85-8369-244d57223f91 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Build Date: 11 April 2013  01:05:39PM
xorg-server 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.13 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.24.4
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Jul 16 17:37:57 2013
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"

Fatal server error:
no screens found

Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.

 ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

***EDIT:***

It seems like solving this problem is like rocket science, its unfixed. Instead of wasting time debugging it, i finally re-install the ubuntu.

Comment: Try `sudo startx` what happens?

Comment: @Mitch: FAILS  (no luck)

Comment: Please post the contents of /var/log/Xorg.0.log to pastebin and link it. Without having any clue what could be wrong, you could try to move /etc/X11/xorg.conf and all files in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d to a backup directory.

Comment: @soulsource: here plz find: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5881280/

Comment: This is strange. It seems that the Intel graphics card driver does not find, or more probable, cannot use your graphics chip. What happened before your system stopped working? Is the hardware detection at least correct, meaning, is it an Intel graphics chip?

Comment: @soulsource: yes its working perfect when i 1st install and when i use LiveCD, but suddently now it does not work at all when i run from Disk. but when i use liveCD it works

Comment: Since it seemed to be an issue with the intel driver, you could try to purge and reinstall it: `sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video-intel` and `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel`, but I'm not too optimistic that this will help. Be careful when purging - I have no clue which other packages might depend on it... Another possible cause would be that you might have updated this package to xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-quantal - in that case, you can try to remove xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-quantal and install xserver-xorg-video-intel again.

Comment: @soulsource: just did it, but no luck still same, it boots to terminal without having any GUI at all.

Comment: Ok,I have to confess, I have no clue what else could be the cause.

Comment: sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop    this worked like a charm

Answer (score 51):

Try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: I have SSH access and CTRL+ALT+F1 terminal access only. There i have done also reinstall of ubuntu-desktop. After reboot still same.

Comment: @YumYumYum - what display manager did you have before ?! go to protected mode as root then do try reinstall of different packages:

Comment: @YumYumYum how do I go back to UI after CTRL+ALT+F1 ?

Comment: I've opened terminal with Alt+F2 when my ubuntu stops during the boot. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: works also with lubuntu-desktop :)

Comment: works also with gdm3 (gnome)

Comment: I hit `esc` key during boot to enter into recovery mode and login via terminal.  Some useful info here https://www.wikihow.tech/Recover-Ubuntu

Comment: THIS SAVE ME!!!! xD

Comment: It worked like a charm. You saved my day. I had uninstalled python for some reason. After re

Comment: I uninstalled libwebkitgtk and my desktop went away on Ubuntu 22.04.  Phew...this answer saved the day!!! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 14):

Follow below instructions:

1. `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
2. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`
3. restart your computer and go to desktop

Answer (score 8):

What display manager did you have before? Go to protected mode as root with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> Then try reinstalling the following packages:

```
apt-get install --reinstall xorg-xserver*
apt-get install --reinstall gdm
apt-get install --reinstall unity
```

In case you have a different display manager than gdm, type `kdm` or `lightdm`.

I once had that too - regarding nvidia-drivers ...

Comment: FAILED - not working, still boots in the terminal screen, no desktop.

Comment: @YumYumYum - you still did not tell, what window-manager you used ? It was unity ? What happens if you install gnome ? or KDE ?

Comment: Unity, default Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: @YumYumYum - have you seen my 2nd answer ?! getting closer to solution ?

Comment: this worked for me between running the command on `xorg` and `gdm3` (ubuntu 18)

Comment: I logged out of the i3 window manager and my gui crahsed. I hade the same issues as described in this questions. reinstalling i3 resolved them.

Comment: This solution worked for me !

Answer (score 7):

when I encounter this on my machine I simply delete the /etc/X11/xorg.conf and restart the system. BUT - I always make backups! :)

Comment: Dont had any xorg.conf file even.

Comment: hm.. you can try this ::    sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg

but please be carefull, or try to see what youtube is showing on this topic.

Comment: Tried did not solved, wired

Comment: I just built a new computer, took the hard disk from my laptop, put it in my new desktop, but couldn't get X working with the new hardware.  Deleted the xorg.conf and immediately everything worked perfectly!  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me were the following two commands and then rebooting

```
sudo apt install xorg
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Answer (score 2):

There was posted in Ubuntu-forum this here to solve the problem after

"Stopping userspace bootsplash" appears like in your boot-log:

With the proprietary drivers installed they did the following:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> (To open up a terminal)
and after login:

```
sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh -a

reboot
```

Entered Grub recovery mode and selected "repair damaged packages"

```
reboot
```

Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> to get to grub menu
hit <kbd>E</kbd> to enter temporary changes into grub
place 'vmalloc=192MB' next to quiet splash

<kbd>F10</kbd>

And problem now solved ?!

They then made the change permanent by editing the `/etc/default/grub` to include:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash vmalloc=192MB"
```

Maybe this solves your problem ? Let me know !

Comment: @YumYumYum - you have settled the rest after reboot ?

Comment: no - it is the grub repair modus - when pressing shift - not reaching this ? "recovery mode" ? - well, but thats already much ! now supergrub-CD would help ?!

Comment: Step 1: clean/autoclean/all done Step 2: changed the grub settings Step 3: update-grub / update-grub2 is applied. but still i have same problem booting in to terminal no GUI.

Comment: have you read that after 2nd reboot ? read the lines slowly. press 'shift' to get to grub menu and hit 'e' (for edit) - read above.

Comment: YES - those are done, basically if you do it after login permanently its same. /etc/default/grub is same by hitting shift/e.

Comment: Don't know how to proceed - could be something quite different and banal: a) you ask this guy here - he solved it: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2147113     b) it is banal and only a wrong spell-checking about directories ? like here:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/65852/cannot-login-to-my-user-account/67723#67723   - more I have not found out ... soon bedtime here.

Comment: i removed the ~/.Xauthority file but still not fixed (From your second link).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9683/discussion-between-dschinn1001-and-yumyumyum)

Comment: worked for me just by making clean, autoclean, autoremove and reboot. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and none of the solutions posted here worked.
What worked for me is the following:

```
     sudo apt-get upgrade
     sudo reboot
```

Commands such as apt-get update where not working before reboot. After rebooting I opened a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and updated everything

```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and everything seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a gui installed and it boots to command line, then you can use the following command:

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently got this problem. So the problem is, changing the default display manager or deleting the daemon associated with it. My default display manager was gdm3, but mistakenly I installed xdm and hence while installation I choose xdm. But when I understood the problem, I removed xdm hoping the default would go back to gdm3, but it didn't go. Instead I got a terminal screen popping uo each time I login. It was frustrating at first, but just a singlr line will make it work...

`sudo apt install xdm`

When the window to choose the default display manager pop up, choose gdm3 ( yes it was still present) and press ok. Now reboot the system to put a smile on your face.