# Ubuntu boots on terminal only after installing ubuntu desktop, how do get GUI desktop

Tags: boot, command-line, 17.04, vmware-player

Same Question:

[Ubuntu boots on terminal only, how do I recover the GUI desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320691/ubuntu-boots-on-terminal-only-how-do-i-recover-the-gui-desktop?newreg=3eda8986cef748a38093f69454350850)

> My System configuration

```
Host System: windows 10
Vmware playstation 12.0
Ubuntu 17.04 64 bit
```

earlier i have installed ubuntu 32 bit but for some reason it was not starting(was working fine earlier and i was working on it but windows defender deleted some files so it's stop working) so had remove it and trying to install 64 bit version. It installed successfully but boots on terminal only.

after searching lots of stuff from google,i have tried

try `sudo startx`
but it gives not found so installed/reinstalled ubuntu desktop using
`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`
installed successfully.
run `sudo startx` but it was opening another inner terminal with white screen but not GUI.

Please let me know what i can try else to recover?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found one solution from YouTube,
i run these command

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get tasksel
```

and then select the fetures i wanted to install, i had selected `Ubuntu desktop` and `basic ubuntu servers` then press ok. it will install the GUI and after that reboot the OS using`sudo reboot` commnand.