# What does this WebKit problem indicate? How do I fix it on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS?

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, webkit

I'm having a webkit issue on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

I get the following errors when running a [Photino app](https://www.tryphotino.io/) (dotnet dev framework which implements webkit).

```
KMS: DRM_IOCTL_MODE_CREATE_DUMB failed: Permission denied
Failed to create GBM buffer of size 600x400: Permission denied
KMS: DRM_IOCTL_MODE_CREATE_DUMB failed: Permission denied
Failed to create GBM buffer of size 600x400: Permission denied
KMS: DRM_IOCTL_MODE_CREATE_DUMB failed: Permission denied
Failed to create GBM buffer of size 600x400: Permission denied
Failed to create EGL images for DMABufs with file descriptors -1, -1 and -1
```

I searched and found Ubuntu [official docs about WebKit](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WebKit).

From there I [tried the test](http://acid3.acidtests.org/) and I see the following results (anything less than 100 indicates a problem).

[image: webkit test & error]

The docs mention that you should have a 100, but it doesn't mention:

1. What a 97 means
2. Any extra docs to check and see what a less-than 100 means
3. any indication of anything else

Does anyone know what that means or how to get more information?

How can I determine which version of WebKit I'm running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still having this issue, but I've discovered a few things:

**1. The Version of WebKit I'm running**

Running the following command helped me discover which version of webkit is installed and running:

`$ apt list --installed | grep -i "webkit"`

I see the following after running that:

> libwebkit2gtk-**4.0-37**/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now
> 2.42.3-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [installed] libwebkit2gtk-**4.1-0**/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now
> 2.42.3-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [installed]

I then discovered there is a bug in the version that is running on ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS / Gnome.

There are [details about it here](https://github.com/elementary/browser/discussions/104).

There is also a bug filed for it [in bugzilla here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=254807).

However, I cannot seem to fix the issue on my machine since it is going to require that the OS and/or Gnome update to the latest fix.

**What I Tried**

Yesterday, I tried removing the older version of webkitgtk and I lost my entire desktop.  Luckily I was able to [follow the instructions here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320691/ubuntu-boots-on-terminal-only-how-do-i-recover-the-gui-desktop) to get my desktop going again.

**Updated NVidia Driver: Problem Solved**

I updated to a newer version of the nvidia driver and the problem was resolved.

[image: new nvidia driver]