# Which NVidia driver should I be running? Is it possible to change the driver (as a test) and easily revert back?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, video

Here's the driver I'm currently running on my NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS & X11.

[image: nvidia drivers & current settings]

How can I know which one that is best?

Is it possible to switch to another one and try it out and easily switch back?

I want to try another one but I'm not sure if I'll lose all video display.

Answer (score 2):

Use command line. If the desktop breaks you can always fall back on command line. So learn that method and you are better off.

To list available drivers

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers list
```

To install:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install [driver:version from list]
```

Help:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers -h
Usage: ubuntu-drivers [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --gpgpu              gpgpu drivers
  --free-only          Only consider free packages
  --package-list PATH  Create file with list of installed packages (in install
                       mode)
  --no-oem             Do not include OEM enablement packages (these enable an
                       external archive)
  -h, --help           Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  autoinstall  Deprecated, please use "install" instead
  debug        Print all available information and debug data about drivers.
  devices      Show all devices which need drivers, and which packages...
  install      Install a driver [driver[:version][,driver[:version]]]
  list         Show all driver packages which apply to the current system.
  list-oem     Show all OEM enablement packages which apply to this system
```

Answer (score -1):

I went ahead and tried switching to another driver (which I'm guessing is newer).  I had my fingers crossed.

Switched to the 535 driver shown:

[image: switch to the nvidia 535 driver]

It took a moment to install the drivers and then I saw no noticeable difference and things seems to be fine.

**Why I Wanted To Change**

I was getting an error when I ran programs which used WebKit which looked like the following:

> KMS: DRM_IOCTL_MODE_CREATE_DUMB failed: Permission denied Failed to
> create GBM buffer of size 800x600: Permission denied KMS:

> DRM_IOCTL_MODE_CREATE_DUMB failed: Permission denied Failed to create
> GBM buffer of size 800x600: Permission denied KMS:

> DRM_IOCTL_MODE_CREATE_DUMB failed: Permission denied Failed to create
> GBM buffer of size 800x600: Permission denied Failed to create EGL
> images for DMABufs with file descriptors -1, -1 and -1

I've been researching this issue for a while now - [see this for more info](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1494477/what-does-this-webkit-problem-indicate-how-do-i-fix-it-on-ubuntu-22-04-3-lts/1498375#1498375).

It caused the WebKit portion of a [Photino](https://www.tryphotino.io/) app to not render.

**Newer NVidia Driver Fixed It**

Right after installing the driver (no reboot) I attempted to the run the photino app which uses WebKit and it ran with no issues -- the errors shown above no longer occur.

However, I did see the following in the console window where I started the app:

> ** (HelloPhotino.NET:45407): WARNING **: 15:03:30.249: Disabled hardware acceleration because GTK failed to initialize GL: Unable to
> create a GL context. libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen