# Can't login to User profile on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: login

When I try to log into my user profile, the screen turns black and then just returns to the log-in menu.

What to do?

Schould I "repair" Ubuntu. If yes, how is it done?

I can't choose to "repair" like in Windows when I boot up with the Ubuntu installation USB I got.

Comment: Try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/65852/cannot-login-to-my-user-account

Answer (score 0):

Got the problem, found the answer :

- Log into your account using a terminal, which you can reach using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>.
- Look at the permissions for your `.Xauthority` file, using `ls -la ~/.Xauthority`.

It needs to be readable and writeable by your user :

```
-rw------- 1 you yourgroup .Xauthority
```

(usually, group and user are the same for regular users)

If your permissions are invalid, you can apply a fix by doing :

```
chown you:yourgroup ~/.Xauthority
chmod 600 ~/.Xauthority
```

- Then go back to your display manager with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>, and try again !
- If it still fails, have a look a your X11 logs, and share : `cat /var/log/Xorg.log.0 | tail -n50`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding not being able to log in on the usual Ubuntu 12.04 screen. I had this problem after installing some software. After checking that my user name owned my home directory and files such as .Xauthority I read an article about checking the main /tmp directory permissions and ownership. To my horror I found that the software package install script had taken ownership of the /tmp directory, which meant that no user could log in because they did not have permission to use the /tmp directory, which all users do require.
The solution was:
Press the **CTRL,** **ALT**, and **F1** keys at the same time when in the usual log in screen.
This takes you to a login request. Then enter your normal user name and press enter.
When prompted enter your usual password and press enter.
You should then be shown a line ending with the $ sign.
This will take you into your home directory, for example /home/tim.
Change to the main root directory by typing in 'cd /' and press the enter key.
type in 'sudo chmod 777 /tmp' and press the enter key, then enter your normal password.
type in 'sudo chmod +t /tmp' and press the enter key and then your password.
type in 'sudo chown root:root /tmp' and press the enter key then you password.
type in 'ls -l /' and press enter key.
you should see in the file list the entry 'drwxrwxrwt root root
The permissions are now correct.
Press the '**CTRL**, **ALT**, and **F7**' keys to return to the usual Ubuntu login screen.
Hopefully this will now work.
Tim