# Login session problem

Tags: login

I can't log in into my session because after I insert the password I got blank screen and I can't log to the desktop, but if I choose guest session at login screen the desktop start normally, I don't know what is the problem so can anyone help me and sorry for my english.

Comment: I had a problem like this and this link helped me: http://askubuntu.com/questions/65852/cannot-login-to-my-user-account