# Ubuntu is booting to usual desktop but to a command prompt

Tags: 15.10

I was using Ubuntu 14.04, after updating it to 15.10 using terminal I restarted the system. But then it started to boot into a Terminal similar to MS-DOS. And I've keyed in my credentials then the next prompt was " To run a command as admin (user'root'), use "sudo " ".

How can I solve this. I got important files in the hard drive.

Comment: Try reinstalling the Desktop package: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem occurring to me (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS). I thought it was because I was trying out `startx` -command with sudo.

Later I found out that the ~/.Xauthority -file was being owned by root, so at the login screen I hit `ctrl+alt+f2` and from there I changed the ownership back to me (`sudo chown user:user .Xauthority`) and was able to login again.

Comment: I've tried it, but it prompts "chown: invalid user: 'user:salman' ". What should I do then. Would please suggest any other method. Please elaborate as I'm kind of newbie to command shell operations.

Comment: have you tried running this command `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` as suggested by @Bhardwaj Raju

Comment: also try to run `sudo init 5` .

Comment: also have a look at this answer - http://askubuntu.com/a/67723  , it seems to have solved this issue for many users.